# Why does c# built-in IO classes is faster than self-made ones?

Tags: c#, performance, io, stream

When I decided to make my own implementation of Java `ByteBuffer` in C# I thought it would be faster than `MemoryStream` + `BinaryWriter`/`BinaryReader`. I looked at their source through ILSpy and there was a lot of checks and helper methods calls, while in my implementation I work directly with an underlying array of bytes. But I was very surprised when tests showed that method calls of heavy built-in classes is almost two times faster than the calls of my light methods.

For example:

```
public void WriteBytes(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
{
    this.EnsureFreeSpace(count);

    Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, offset, this.buffer, this.position, count);

    this.position += count;
    if (this.length < this.position)
    {
        this.length = this.position;
    }
}

public void ReadBytes(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
{
    this.EnsureDataExist(count);

    Buffer.BlockCopy(this.buffer, this.position, buffer, offset, count);

    this.position += count;
}

private void EnsureFreeSpace(Int32 count)
{
    if (this.buffer.Length - this.position < count)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}

private void EnsureDataExist(Int32 count)
{
    if (this.length - this.position < count)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

~1.5-2 times slower than

```
memoryStream.Write(...)
memoryStream.Read(...)
```

in this simple tests

```
Byte[] temp = new byte[64];
stopWatch.Restart();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    ms.Write(temp, 0, temp.Length);
    ms.Position = 0;
    ms.Read(temp, 0, temp.Length);
    ms.Position = 0;
}
stopWatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

stopWatch.Restart();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    mb.WriteBytes(temp, 0, temp.Length);
    mb.Position = 0;
    mb.ReadBytes(temp, 0, temp.Length);
    mb.Position = 0;
}
stopWatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Why?

In all test optimization was enabled. In Debug mode average difference was as I said ~1.7 times. In Release mode ~1.3 times, less but still there.

**EDIT**
Thanks to the advice I found that outside of Visual Studio my code is several times faster or at least as fast as built-in code. So now the question is, why this is happening?

Comment: Microsoft isn't paying its programmers for nothing :D

Comment: How do you benchmark it? Debug mode? or release mode? Optimizations enabled/disabled ?

Comment: You aren't conducting your test properly. First, you have to test in Release mode, next, you have to "warm up" JIT and let it compile your code.

Comment: You use `BlockCopy` which I find not to be as fast as you may think (try with `Array.Copy`). While `Write` method deals with byte array using indexes which is quite fast operation.

Comment: With optimization enabled and "Debug" mode the difference was as I said ~1.7 times. With optimization enabled and "Release" mode the difference was ~1.3 times, less but still there.

Comment: @Leri I've tried both `BlockCopy` and `ArrayCopy` and they gave similar performance. As for `Write` method of `MemoryStream` it uses `Buffer.InternalBlockCopy`.

Comment: Which test is first?  Maybe the second catches a GC pack.

Comment: @Rob I've tried both variants and the results were the same.

Comment: I've never tried it myself, but maybe some `ngen` on your code could help?

Comment: @PMF I also never used it, I'll try to look at it. Actually I do not want to speed up my code but to understand why it is slower.

Comment: @Menzoda: The framework code is usually ngen'd during installation, so this might be the reason it is faster. Just guessing.

Comment: Have you run it separately from Visual Studio

Comment: @Rob Bingo! Outside from Visual Studio my code is several times faster  than built-in (or at least as fast as built-in)! Can you explain why this is happening and post the answer?

Comment: FYI, C# has no built-in IO classes at all.

Comment: By that I mean the classes that come with the .Net framework.

Comment: Build in classes aren't JITted, they use pre-compiled images (using ngen). Running in the debugger suppresses JIT optimization by default (there is an option to change this).

Comment: I cannot explain it fully - but I have seen similar. I wrote a cache program in (native) C++ that would take 60% CPU running in VS and 2% running outside. I think VS collects more data than it shows.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Actually the C# spec specifies that it implements the CLI BCL, which `System.IO` is a part of. So, I would say that your statement about C# having no IO classes is pretty incorrect. If I attempt to remove the reference to `mscorlib` in Visual Studio, it complains that I do not have various System.IO` classes implemented, among numerous others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take is that you're failing to test its performance correctly. This topic has been covered several times before and I find this blog series by Eric Lippert very enlightening: http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one

As a shortcut, do the following: put whole test code inside a for loop and run several times, compare the output and always discard the first result.